# Combinations on a list in python

Tags: python, list, combinations, python-itertools

So I got a list in python like this:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

And I want the combinations between the number 3 with every number something like this:

```
[(1,3),(2,3),(3,4)]
```

Is there something I can use? I know there is something called itertools, but I'm kinda new so i'm not sure how to use it.

Thank you!

Comment: itertools combinations and permutations is well documented, with  many samples on this site.  Try it out

Comment: You should not need `itertools` for this.

Comment: do you want this output: `[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]` ?

Comment: No exactly, just one position (in this case 3) to the other positions

Comment: the order of the elements matter ? (4,3) is fine ? as an element ?

Comment: Yeah (4,3) is also fine as an element.

Comment: How do you choose this `3`? By index or by value? What should happen if you have several `3` in your list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use a list comprehension:

```
orig_list = [1,2,3,4]
[(entry, 3) for entry in orig_list if entry != 3] # [(1, 3), (2, 3), (4, 3)]
```

If you're not interested in duplicate values you can make it into a set:

```
orig_list = set([1,2,3,4])
[(entry, 3) for entry in orig_list if entry != 3] # [(1, 3), (2, 3), (4, 3)]
```

Comment: usually you use `_` as a variable if you do not want to use that variable

Comment: This is great it helped me a lot thank you!, what if I also want the other position? No just (1,3) but also (3,1)?

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do this is using a loop:

```
list2 = []
for x in list1:
     list2.append((x,3))
print(list2)
```

If you want to get rid of (3,3) use:

```
list2 = []
for x in list1:
     if x != 3:
          list2.append((x,3))
print(list2)
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use list comprehension with [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
import itertools

[e for e in itertools.combinations([1,2,3,4], 2) if 3 in e]
```

output:

```
[(1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
```

even better you could use `itertools.repeat`:

```
from itertools import repeat

l = [1,2,3,4]
[(f, s) for f, s in zip(l, repeat(3)) if f != 3]
```

output:

```
[(1, 3), (2, 3), (4, 3)]
```

Comment: Note: This turns a `O(n)` problem into a `O(n²)` problem (n choose 2 is `n * (n - 1) / 2` work); for every value you generate, you have to filter out ~`n`. Fine if the input is length 4, less so if it's length 1000.

Comment: my second solution is O(n) time complexity, should be just fine, maybe the fastest

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
l = [1,2,3,4]
[(l[i], 3) for i in range(l.index(3))] + [(3, l[i]) for i in range(l.index(3)+1, len(l))]
```

which gives the output:

```
[(1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
```